# Submit column values in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, foreach, model, html-table, submit

I'm using ASP.Net MVC3, I've a View in which I'm displaying a simple Table with Model Data as follows:

```
+-------+---------------+----------------+
|  ID   |   Name        | Order          |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
|  ID   |   Name        |  textbox val=1 |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
|  ID   |   Name        |  textbox val=3 |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
|  ID   |   Name        |  textbox val=2 |
+-------+---------------+----------------+

+-------+    +--------------+
|submit |    | update order |
+-------+    +--------------+
```

Here, Order column contains Inputbox with Order values (1,3,2 etc.,). I need to Update my Model `[Item {ID, Name, Order}]`by reading Order column.

Meaning, I need to submit the Order values to Model, by reading a HTML table column. How to do this?

Comment: where is your code that does this? can you provide some code?

Comment: @DarthVader That's what I'm asking, I don't have any Idea on this. I'm new to MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view model for each item:

```
    public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

And a model for the action:

```
    public class EditViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> Items { get;set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
    }
```

Render the rows like this:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="Id[@Model.Index]" value="@item.Id" />@item.Id</td>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Value[@Model.Index]" value="@item.Value" /></td>
        </tr>
        @{ Model.Index = Model.Index + 1 }
    }
```

And finally receive the rows as:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ItemViewModel[] items)
    {

    }
```